# OnInspectorGUI: get selected field of a Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my editor I have

```
Vector3 v3Pos = EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field ("Position", myTarget.posV3);
if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck ()) {
  // code
}
```

I would like to use two buttons marked with "-" and "+" that allow to simulate dragging mouse on an axis to change the values.
Once selected one of the three fields of Vector3 I will get a precise movement of the object with each click on the chosen axis.
Problem is not code but how to identify which field between X, Y, Z was selected.
I saw EditorGUIUtility.hotControl but it is not clear to me whether I can get which axis was selected with it.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you are trying to archive. Maybe you could add more code of what you are trying

Comment: It is not a code problem. In my editor I have a Vector3 field. It is connected to an object on scene. When I place the cursor on one of the three labels X, Y, Z, Unity's typical behavior is to allow you to move the object. I have to put two buttons that do the same thing. When I click in one of the three fields of the Vector 3 it is selected. I have to understand from code which field was selected to connect it on the fly with my two buttons.

Comment: This way instead of dragging with the mouse to move the object I will click on one of the two buttons getting the same thing with a more precise result.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like actually you will need 3 [`FloatField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.FloatField.html)s instead to re-build a custom Vector3 like view using [`GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl.html) and [`GUI.SetNextControlName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.SetNextControlName.html) and doing

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("position");
EditorGUILayout.LabelField("X", GUILayout.Width(12));
GUI.SetNextControlName("myX");
var floatX = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(myTarget.posV3.x);

EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Y", GUILayout.Width(12));
GUI.SetNextControlName("myY");
var floatY = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(myTarget.posV3.y);

EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Z", GUILayout.Width(12));
GUI.SetNextControlName("myZ");
var floatZ = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(myTarget.posV3.z);
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Currently selected field is " + GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl(), MessageType.None);

EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

var selectedField = GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl();

if (GUILayout.Button("-"))
{
    switch (selectedField)
    {
        case "myX":
            floatX -= 0.01f;
            break;

        case "myY":
            floatY -= 0.01f;
            break;

        case "myZ":
            floatZ -= 0.01f;
            break;
    }
}

if (GUILayout.Button("+"))
{
    switch (selectedField)
    {
        case "myX":
            floatX += 0.01f;
            break;

        case "myY":
            floatY += 0.01f;
            break;

        case "myZ":
            floatZ += 0.01f;
            break;
    }
}

EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

myTarget.posV3 = new Vector3(floatX, floatY, floatZ);
```

However I'm not sure this would give you better control since afaik `OnInpsctorGUI` is not called constantly like `Update` but rather in irregular intervals.

Additionally everytime you click the button, the field will lose the focus actually so you'll have to set it back again.

---

You will also notice that it is basically **but** .. you won't see the change until the field loses focus ... I'ld rather recommend to write a complete [`CustomPropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomPropertyDrawer.html) for the `Vector3` and instead use [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) and [`EditorGUILayout.PropertyField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html)

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I do not know if it depends on the recent version of Unity but field does not lose focus by clicking on the button. Object moves with each click. But as you said, floatfield is not updated while Vector3 is updated with every click.. Moreover I would still need the typical unity behavior on the X, Y, Z labels. I have to move the object quickly and only at the end use the buttons. Too bad that I can not access the three fields of a Vector3 with GetNameOfFocusedControl.
I think I really should write a CustomPropertyDrawer. I'll think about it. Thanks for your help.